# Problem inserting a class into body element with property binding through a component method

Tags: angular

I just started learning Angular and it's my first post on Stackoverflow, sorry if my question seems too obvious, but I really couldn't find the answer on my own...

The project is made of two components, one inside of another.
There's a `<table>` on the "outside" one, and I need a (click) event on it's `<tr>` tag to trigger a property binding into the body element of the page, especifically to insert a class that is saved into the .scss global file, with the property "overflow: hidden".
I already exported the outside's component and imported it into the app.module, though it didn't seem to make a difference.

Chrome reads the html code as if there wasn't any brackets there...

Chrome's F12 ->

```html
<body [class.body-overflow-hidden]=" displayBody == bodyoverflowhidden'" class="theme-origin">
```

## Index.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Time de Vendas</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./assets/img/favicon.png">
</head>

<body [class.body-overflow-hidden]=" displayBody == 'bodyoverflowhidden'" class="theme-origin">

  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

## App.module

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ExtratopilotoModule } from './extratopiloto/extratopiloto.module';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { NotFoundComponent } from './error/not-found/not-found.component';
import { FeedComponent } from './feed/feed.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './profile/profile.component';
import { TopsComponent } from './tops/tops.component';
import { StatementComponent } from './profile/statement/statement.component';
import { ExtratopilotoComponent } from './extratopiloto/extratopiloto.component';

@NgModule({

  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    NotFoundComponent,
    FeedComponent,
    ProfileComponent,
    TopsComponent,
    StatementComponent,
  ],

  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ExtratopilotoModule
  ],

  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

## Outside component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-extratopiloto',
  templateUrl: './extratopiloto.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./extratopiloto.component.scss']
})

export class ExtratopilotoComponent implements OnInit {
  display: string = '';
  displayBody: string = '';
  displayProposal() {
    this.display = "modal-on";
    this.displayBody = "bodyoverflowhidden";
  }

  hideProposal() {
    this.display = "";
    this.displayBody = "";
  }
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

## Outside module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { ExtratopilotoComponent } from './extratopiloto.component';

@NgModule({

  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    ExtratopilotoComponent
  ],
  exports: [ExtratopilotoComponent]
})

export class ExtratopilotoModule { }
```

## Edit:

file -> "outside component"

If someone ever needs to know exatcly how the code ended, here it is:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Renderer2} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-extratopiloto',
  templateUrl: './extratopiloto.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./extratopiloto.component.scss']
})
export class ExtratopilotoComponent implements OnInit {

  display: string = '';
  displayBody: string = '';

  displayProposal() {
    this.display = "modal-on";
    this.renderer.addClass(document.body, 'body-overflow-hidden');
  }

  hideProposal() {
    this.display = "";
    this.renderer.removeClass(document.body, 'body-overflow-hidden');
  }


  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: Your expression binding is outside of any angular component. So it can't work. You cn only use property binding inside component templates.

Comment: Ok, didn't know about that, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that instead of trying to tie those components together perhaps you should contain all the logic inside of 1 component

try to use Renderer2

import it into the component that contains your click event

```
export class ExtratopilotoComponent implements OnInit {    
    constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) { }

    onChangeBodyClick() {
       this.renderer.addClass(document.body, 'bodyoverflowhidden');
    }
}
```

This way your code is cleaner overall and you only have to look in 1 place to make changes.

Comment: It worked! Just had to make a few adaptations. Next step is to learn about this Renderer2 that I didn't know before! Thank you very much!!!